# how do I select something from a table and output to a label?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

Using odbc how do I select something from a table and output to a label on my asp.net page?

```
    {

        OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite; User=root; Password=;");
        cn.Open();
        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM User (FirstName, SecondName)", cn);
        OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Name.Text = (reader[0].ToString());

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ExecuteNonQuery will not give you a output, it executes a Transact-SQL statement against the connection and returns the number of rows affected. See [ExecuteReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k.aspx) or [BeginExecuteReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1a674khd.aspx) instead. These links also contain examples to help you :-)

You might want to change it to something like:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
      Name.Text = (reader[0].ToString());
}
```

Comment: Please see added code in my answer. You might want to try it out and see if the formatting of the reader[0] is what you what too.

Comment: cant convert object to string

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [OdbcDataReader class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcdatareader.aspx)